# OleDBDataAdapter error while declaring query

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub btnsave_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnsave.Click
    adt = New OleDbDataAdapter ("insert into tb1 (job station,status,frekuensi,durasi,rata-rata) values ('"& lblstation.Text &"','" & lblstatus.Text &"','"& lblfrekuensi.Text &"','"&lbldurasi.Text&"','" &lblrata.Text& "')",dbconn)
    adt.Fill(ds)
    ds = New DataSet
    MsgBox("kesimpen")
End Sub
```

When I  declare `'"& lblfrekuensi.Text &"'` and `'"&lbldurasi.Text&"'`, I receive an error message:

> Type character '&' does not match declared data type 'String'

and

> Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'New' accepts this number of arguments

and

> Comma, ')', or a valid expression continuation expected.

I'm sorry if my english is bad. I try to check my code again but I can't find any solution. What shall I do?

Comment: Your code is messy and this is why that's bad. You leave spaces in some places and not others.  Always leave spaces on both sides of operators, identifiers, etc.  Put spaces where they belong and the issue will go away.

Comment: On top of what @jmcilhinney has said, look into the use of parameters which will resolve this issue as well as other foreseeable issues.

Comment: `lbldurasi.Text&` needs a space.  Google "vb.net bobby tables" to find out why you must never write code like this.

Comment: Just as a side note, please also tag with the backend you are using (though below I wrote it as backend neutral).

Answer (score 0):

Simply use parameters, never ever write such SQL strings with concatenation.

```
Private Sub btnsave_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnsave.Click
    dim mySql as string  = <sql>
insert into tb1 
  ([job station],status,frekuensi,durasi,[rata-rata]) 
values 
  (?,?,?,?,?)
</sql> 
    adt = New OleDbDataAdapter (mySql,dbconn)
    adt.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("jobStation", OleDbType.Varchar).Value = lblstation.Text 
    adt.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("status", OleDbType.Varchar).Value = lblstatus.Text
   adt.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("frekuensi", OleDbType.Varchar).Value = lblfrekuensi.Text
    adt.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("duration", OleDbType.Varchar).Value = lbldurasi.Text
    adt.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("ratarata", OleDbType.Varchar).Value = lblrata.Text

    ds = New DataSet
    adt.Fill(ds)
    MsgBox("kesimpen")
End Sub
```

Using parameters:

- Prevent SQL injection attacks.
- Prevent nasty quoting errors (and also values themselves might contain quotes, ampersand ...)
- Provides passing values correctly.
- Provide much better readability.